# How costly is enableBlending() and disableBlending()?

Tags: java, libgdx

Is it worth it to enable blending directly before something that needs it and disable it right after or is it better to just keep it enabled the whole way through? The reason why this question came up is that the documentation for disable/enableBlending() says:

> Disables blending for drawing sprites. Calling this within
>   begin()/end() will flush the batch.

As far as I am aware flushing can have a performance impact if done very often in one frame. I would be very happy if someone could clarify which is the better option.

Comment: First of all, don't do anything, unless it is really needed. If your game is running slow on any device you want it to run on, then you can start optimizing it. To the question: It depends on the case. If you have to enable/disable blending quite often, it may decrease the performance cause of the `flush`-calls. If you instead only enable/disable it once and draw many things, it might increase performance. Usualy it is disabled, then the background is drawn, then enabled and the rest is drawn.

Comment: Thanks allot for your answer :)
You could write it as an official answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I did not post it as an answer, cause it is just my opinion and i don't have any "evidence" for it. But if it helped you it's fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't do anything, unless it is really needed.
If your game is running slow on any device you want it to run on, then you can start optimizing it.
To the question: It depends on the case. If you have to enable/disable blending quite often, it may decrease the performance cause of the flush-calls.
If you instead only enable/disable it once and draw many things, it might increase performance.
Usualy blending is disabled to draw the background and then enabled to draw the rest.